# Very slow menu_tree_check_access query - how to debug

Tags: 7, nodes, database, performance

I have a Drupal System which is running fine in production and locally but the dev/cons Db seems to have a problem.
After looking a bit deeper into it I found that menu_tree_check_access takes 3.8 Sec to finish!

First I thougt there must be something wrong with the DB-Server but everything is fine there.

After I started a node permissions rebuild everything was suddenly quick again. But after the node permissions rebuild finished it was slow again. 
So I guess there has been added some strange test content that creates some kind of infinite loop or something else.

Any ideas how to debug this? How can I run the slow query against another fresh DB from Prod e.g. with devel I only see the query with placeholders.

Comment: If you have access to administer the DB, start here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html and then it'll be clearer if it's a slow DB query or a PHP-related issue.

Comment: Do you know use xdebug? Let break poin at line 1498 in file includes/menu.inc. Check how many items in array **$node_links**. I thing it's big number.

Comment: @Jonh yes I do know xdebug and will have a look after it.

Comment: Checked the slow query log as you said @AlfredArmstrong and run the query by hand again the bad and a good db - speed was okay at both but couldn't run the subquery which might be the problem.

Comment: @macbert How about debug? Did you find anything?